# windows server 2012 remote desktop - Send messages between standard users

Tags: permissions, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

Does anyone know the policy, or registry change, etc. for allowing messages (on the same server) between standard users...

an elevated cmd prompt or task manager works of course... but need it to work on standard accounts.

```
H:\>msg scott hi
Error sending message to session RDP-Tcp#0 : Error 5
Error [5]:Access is denied.
```

(This is windows server 2012)

Also I recall setting something on server 2008 r2, but just can't remember what it was, so it can be done--

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So Microsoft took away the Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration console in Server 2012.  You can still do some things in Server Manager, but I'm not sure if you can modify the properties of the `RDP-Tcp` connection object. This is very annoying.

You can still do this with WMI however.

Here's the MSDN documentation for the ModifyPermissions method of the Win32_TSAccount WMI class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383776(v=vs.85).aspx

So from PowerShell, first get the account whose permissions you want to modify:

```
$TSAccount = @(Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\CIMv2\TerminalServices -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_TSAccount WHERE TerminalName='RDP-TCP' AND AccountName='BUILTIN\\Remote Desktop Users'")
```

You should now have one account object in `$TSAccount`, something like this:

```
...
AccountName        : BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users
AuditFail          : 0
AuditSuccess       : 0
Caption            :
Description        :
InstallDate        :
Name               :
PermissionsAllowed : 289
PermissionsDenied  : 0
SID                : S-1-5-32-555
Status             :
TerminalName       : RDP-Tcp
PSComputerName     : SERVER01
```

PermissionsAllowed is a bitmap.  You want to add `WINSTATION_MSG`, which has a value of 7, to that PermissionsAllowed property.

```
Foreach($account In $TSAccount)
{
    $account.ModifyPermissions(7,1)
}
```

So before the change, the PermissionsAllowed bitmap of decimal 289 looks like this in binary:

`100100001`

But I flipped that 7th bit, so now it looks like:

`110100001`

Which when you convert that back to decimal, is 417.

Someone at MS probably didn't want us to be doing this for them to make it so hard on us, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Open ***Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration*** > Properties of the ***RDP-Tcp*** connection 
object > ***Security tab*** > ***Advanced*** > Edit the entry you are interested in (perhaps remote desktop users security group) > Check the Message check-box

Should work for Windows Server 2012 as well.

[image]

Comment: Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration tool does not exist in 2012!

Comment: That's really suxx. Moreover, server has to be in a domain to access Remote Desktop configuration! Sorry, for being no help. I hoped MS guys would leave it as it was, but unfortunately, - NO.